# What type of metadata -strip removes?

Tags: imagemagick, metadata, strip

-strip actually removes some metadata in case of ImageMagick. What type of metadata actually it removes?

In ImageMagick, it has been noticed that

> strip the image of any profiles, comments or these **PNG** chunks:
>   bKGD,cHRM,EXIF,gAMA,iCCP,iTXt,sRGB,tEXt,zCCP,zTXt,date.

What are these chunks?

What about other format images?

Answer (score 0):

They are chunks that are not necessary for displaying an image.

These are described in the [PNG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11Ancillary-chunks):
bKGD,cHRM,gAMA,iCCP,iTXt,sRGB,tEXt,zTXt.

zCCP is an ICCP profile stored in an iTXt or zTXt chunk.

date: Image creation date and modification date that
would otherwise be autimatically inserted by ImageMagick

EXIF: camera data usually coming from a JPEG or RAW image.

Comment: But it is not at all removing any date created, modified and all. I tried this. Why so? It is under properties: date:create and date:modify

Comment: ImageMagick creates new "date" properties when they aren't found in the input file.  Use "pngcheck -v file.png" to see if they're actually in the file.